# Number of posts in page - set per category and exclude sidebar

Tags: categories

I have a widget in the sidebar that shows recent posts. The code below works to set the number of posts per page in each category, but it also affects the sidebar.
Is there any way to exclude the sidebar?

```
/** Different number of posts per page depending on the category **/
function hwl_home_pagesize( $query ) 
{
    if ( is_category( 'video' ) )
{
    // If you want "showposts"
    $query->query_vars['showposts'] = 10;
    return;
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hwl_home_pagesize', 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `is_main_query` on the query object.

```
if ( is_category( 'video' ) && $query->is_main_query() )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should **always** do the two following checks

- Check that your current query is the main query
- Check that the query is a front end query

`pre_get_posts` alters **all** instances of `WP_query`, front end and back end, so you will need to make double sure you are doing the above checks

Also `is_category()` should be an object of `$query`

Your conditional should look like this

```
if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() )
```