# Only show certain post types in recent posts widget

Tags: pre-get-posts

I have a custom post type which has been made to show in archives using the code below in my theme's `functions.php` :

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
    if ( is_archive() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        $post_types = get_post_types();
        if($post_type)
            $post_type = $post_type;
        else
            $post_type = $post_types;
        $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `pre_get_posts` basically altered the query for recent posts widget, causing it to display all post types in this case. However, since I am using WooCommerce, the shop products are also shown which I would like to avoid.

So, is there any way I can make the recent posts show **only** standard WordPress posts and a custom post type, while keeping the custom post type visible in archives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of posts in page - set per category and exclude sidebar](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170252/number-of-posts-in-page-set-per-category-and-exclude-sidebar)

Comment: Thank you @PieterGoosen! That's exactly what I wanted to achieve but I wasn't aware of `is_main_query`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`widget_posts_args`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/widget_posts_args) filter

```
add_filter('widget_posts_args', 'wpsites_modify_recent_posts_widget');
function wpsites_modify_recent_posts_widget($params) {
$params['post_type'] = array('post', '$post_type');
return $params;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/braddalton/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L569)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think `is_main_query` works better in the sense that it can avoid problems with other widgets / queries in the page by making sure that only the main query is altered to show the custom post type. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170252/number-of-posts-in-page-set-per-category-and-exclude-sidebar

Comment: You could use in_the_loop() as well.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I did a search and found another thread about this : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67716/how-to-determine-if-a-filter-is-called-in-a-sidebar-widget-context
But I'm not sure what's the difference between `in_the_loop` and `is_main_query`? As in, under what cases will one be preferred / work over the other?

Comment: @Billy they are the same. `in_the_loop()` was used before `is_main_query()` existed. Your choice which to use. I personally prefer `is_main_query()`